# Como resolver el error de CORS desde App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Estoy haciendo un formulario de App Script y necesito validar un campo usando una api de verificación de DNI y no logro que funcione en el archivo JS porque me devuelve el ERROR:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.apis.net.pe/v1/ruc?numero=10460278975' from origin 'https://n-xa2gu7eihyolnkqw3dq2j4bd63pxrbifjmf3xma-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Cuando yo utilizo esa api en el archivo  `codigo.gs` si me funciona perfectamente. pero no desde el Javascript y necesito hacer desde ahi la validación.

Dejare el codigo mas relevante:

codigo.gs

```
function doGet() { 
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Registro');
  template.pubUrl = "https://api.apis.net.pe/v1/ruc?numero=";
  var output = template.evaluate()
  .setTitle("Registro de Taller")
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=0.5')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
 
  return output; 
}

function include( fileName ){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile( fileName )
  .getContent();
  

}
function doPost( e ){
  /*
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetRegistro = SS.getSheetByName('Registro');
  var id = new Date();
  var email = e.parameter.email;
  var curso = e.parameter.curso;
  var nombres = e.parameter.nombres;
  var apellidos = e.parameter.apellidos;
  var telefono = e.parameter.telefono;
  var genero = e.parameter.genero;
  var dni = e.parameter.dni;
  var razonSocial = e.parameter.razonSocial;
  var estratoEmpresarial = e.parameter.estratoEmpresarial;
  var actividadEconomica = e.parameter.actividadEconomica;
  var departamento = e.parameter.departamento;
  var provincia = e.parameter.provincia;
  var distrito = e.parameter.distrito;
  var ruc = e.parameter.ruc;
  var acuerdoPrivacidad = ( e.parameter.acuerdoPrivacidad == 'on' ) ? 'Aceptado' : 'Rechazado';

     sheetRegistro.appendRow([ id, ruc, razonSocial, actividadEconomica, departamento, provincia, distrito, nombres, apellidos, dni, genero, email, telefono, acuerdoPrivacidad, estratoEmpresarial, curso ]);

*/
  
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('RegistroTerminado').evaluate();
}
```

JS.html (Solo agrego el codigo de la función que usa la api)

```
    async function getData(ruc){
        ruc = "10460278975";
        let token = "apis-token-1981.duYu0iE1XNVFtZ90TBfgJcmsyXDp58c7";
        let url = "https://api.apis.net.pe/v1/ruc?numero="+ruc;
        let res = await fetch(url, {method:"POST"});
        return res;
    }
getData()
```

Agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: Los mensajes de error deben de agregarse como texto no como imagen. Favor de agregar un [mcve].

Comment: revisa la documentación, el api tienes que invocar desde el backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está bien que hagas el llamado en el archivo `codigo.js`

Importante: En el archivo appsscript.json de tu proyecto agregar el siguiente código para poder utilizar el UrlFetchApp

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
  ]
```

Ejemplo :

```
function getDni(dni){ 
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.apis.net.pe/v1/dni?numero=' + dni);
    return Utilities.jsonParse(response.getContentText())
  } catch (error) {
    return Utilities.jsonParse("{\"error\":\"DNI no existe\"}")   
  }
}
```

En tu archivo `JS.html`

Invocas el método que acabas de crear en codigo.js

```
  function consultaDNI(dni) {
      google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(onSuccessDni)
          .withFailureHandler(onFailureDni)
          .getDni(dni);        
  }

  function onSuccessDni(sHref) 
  {
    console.log('onSuccessDni', sHref)
  }
    
  function onFailureDni(error) 
  {
    console.log('onFailureDni', error.message)
  }
```